# Create a Labeled Number Line in Latex

Tags: latex

How can I create a number line with labels, instead of numbers in Latex?  I have no idea how to even start.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```latex
\documentclass[multi=false,tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\labelz{{"Judicial Independence","Long Label 2","Label 3","Label 4"}}
\draw [<->,>=triangle 45] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x in {1,...,4} {%
        \draw [<->,>=stealth] (2*\x,-.4) -- (2*\x,.4);
        \node at (2*\x,2.4-.4*\x){\pgfmathparse{\labelz[\x-1]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

Then from here you can adjust `scale`, position of lines, shape of arrows ([reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66330/labeling-with-words-with-counter-using-lists/66340#66340)).

Notice if what you're interested in changes depending on `\x`.

Instead, changing

`\node at (2*\x,2.4-.4*\x)`

to

`\node [align=center,text width=22mm] at (2*\x,1)`

youl'll get:

[image: screenshot of output pdf 2]

Comment: ...also changing `Long Label 2` to `Long long Label 2` by the way